# In Half-Life 2, how many people would fit in Combine Dropship's Troop container?

Tags: video-games, half-life

In Half-Life 2, how many people would fit in Combine Dropship's Troop container?

(Or, how many had been deployed at one time at most (max. number I know of is 6, at Lighthouse Point)? And, how many at most map editor actually allows?)

I'd like to know answers both the mechanical and the lore side of the issue at hand.

Answer (score 5):

The [NPC](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Npc_combinedropship) itself only has code for six NPCs to be dropped off by it. You could probably work around it if you were making a map, but as far as I am aware, Valve never used more than those.

The container's in-game model has a surprisingly small space inside when it's open. It only goes about half way back into it:

[image]

However, this could (rather comfortably for Combine standards) fit at least eight:

[image]

If we assume the rest of it is hollow inside that the model doesn't show, this could probably store at least 20 with room for some gear:

[image]

I didn't try to pack them as tightly as possible, so if you were just cramming people inside it could likely pack in 30, but it'll be very cramped.

Comment: There would also be a question of lifting capacity **and balance**.  Even if it can lift 20 soldiers, you can't have a situation where the 20 soldiers move the center of gravity to a position which is incompatible with flight.  Or where them disembarking has that same effect.  It's extra tricky when aircraft drop things inflight, like bombs, paratroops, daughter aircraft etc.